# specifiying datasource bean with intellij is not picking up implented interfaces

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, datasource

[image: I get this error]

`ComboPooledDataSource` implements `javax.sql.datasource` and type is not allowed as an attribute accorind got intellij. I am using the full spring stack version 3.1

Comment: It may be a classpath issue. Check if you have two copies of `javax.sql.DataSource` in your project. just press Ctrl+N and type its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this property to the `dataSource` bean:

```
<b:property name="expectedType" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Comment: "cannot resolve property expectedType" when I try to insert that property into my bean definition, it is not offered up by autocomplete whereas all the others are. I am using http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans,  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

Comment: this is a bug isn't it ? combopooleddatasource implements the datasource interface so there is no reason to display an error in code inspection.

Comment: My suggestion is based on this comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85110#comment=27-326110. If it doesn't work for you, please file a new bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specify any JDK for your project when this happened?

I got the exact same problem with `dbcp BasicDataSource`. It turns out this happened because I haven't specify the JDK for my project. After I set it, the problems are gone.